# How to regenerate controller,view mvc5 asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

I am building a website using asp .net mvc 5 infrastructure,and after a while of work I changed the DB schema, how can I recreate the controller,view? I dont want to have to delete them every time i change the DB.

Answer (score 1):

make the changes in in the model to reflect the new fields, then it's the same procedure as if you would create the controller for the first time, it will as you if you want to replace the controller, views...

Answer (score 0):

Create a new  conntroller with a slightly different name

Copy files you want updated into orignal folder ie Edit.cshtml etc.

Edit view files to use the orignal controller

Delete new controller and new view folder